# Dry Run of Node with maximum child sum in a generic tree

Tags: c++, recursion, tree

I am not getting at the point where ans = 15 and sum = 15. Now 15 does not have any child so it will not go into the for loop. Then will it directly return ans(15) to 1? What will happen next?

Or please explain me the whole dry run part. Input: 5 3 1 2 3 1 15 2 4 5 1 6 0 0 0 0

```
TreeNode<int>* maxSumNode(TreeNode<int> *root){
    /* Don't write main().
     * Don't read input, it is passed as function argument.
     * Return output and don't print it.
     * Taking input and printing output is handled automatically.
     */

    //small calculation
    TreeNode<int>* ans = root;
    int sum = root -> data;
    for(int i = 0; i < root -> children.size(); i++)
    {
        sum = sum + root -> children[i] -> data;
    }


     for(int i = 0; i < root -> children.size(); i++)
    {
        TreeNode<int> *x = maxSumNode(root -> children[i]);
         int xSum = x -> data;
        for(int i = 0; i < x ->children.size(); i++)
        {
            xSum = xSum + x ->children[i] -> data;
        }
         if(xSum > sum)
         {
             ans = x;
             sum = xSum;
         }
    }
    return ans;

}
```

Comment: Have you tried to step through the code statement by statement in a debugger?

Comment: Yup! The code is working fine.